# How do I use Labeled with ErrorListPlot?

Tags: plotting, labeling

Consider the following simple example of using `ListPlot` with `Labeled` data:

```
ListPlot[
 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 6}] // Map[Labeled[#, "Test"] &]
]
```

[image]

So far, so good. Now, I want to do the same with an `ErrorListPlot`, and thus write

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
ErrorListPlot[
 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 6}] // Map[({#, 0.2} &), #, {2}] & // 
  Map[Labeled[#, "Test"] &]
 ]
```

Unfortunately, this just gives me a blank plot.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to use `Labeled` (or similar functionality) to work with an `ErrorListPlot` (possibly without having to reimplement it with `Graphics` primitives)? Note that I'm aware that I can use `PlotLegends`, but that's not what I am looking for (unless it can be used to produce the same kind of output as `Labeled`).

Comment: `ErrorListPlot` is obsolete, unmaintained, and likely hasn't been updated to support wrappers.. Why not use `Around` with `ListPlot`/`ListLinePlot`?

Comment: @user6014 I didn't know it was considered obsolete. Never heard of `Around`. That seems to be the ideal solution, but I don't have v12 so I guess I can't use it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 6}] // Map[({#, 0.2} &), #, {2}]&;
```

You can use [`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html) with `ErrorListPlot`:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];


ErrorListPlot[data,
   Joined -> True, PlotLabels -> {"Test", "Test"}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

As commented by user6014, in versions 12+, you can use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) :

```
data2 = Apply[Around, data, {-2}];
```

Wrapping each dataset with [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) `ListPlot` produces the desired look:

```
ListPlot[Map[Callout[#, "Test"] &] @ data2, 
  Joined -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]